# Change menu at run-time

Tags: java, android

How do I change the options menu at run-time in android 2.3.3? I have two xml menus and need to switch menu type at run-time.

I would like to destroy or update the menu and when the user then presses the menu button, onCreateOptions menu is then called again selecting the appropriate xml menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(OPTIONS_TYPE == 0) // Photo option
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.photomenu, menu);
    else // Photo + delete option
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.photodeletemenu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your code...Should work..., maybe problem in your xml file ?

Comment: Check your both xml files, maybe there are the same ? And you think that you code not working...

Comment: But onCreateOptionsMenu is only called once. i.e when the user presses the options button first

Comment: There is no errors in the xml.. Everything works fine if i go back and forth using the back button :/

Comment: But I want the menu to change without switching activity

Comment: Oh, sorry...didn't understand the question correctly...

Comment: No problem :) Do you know or have an idea of what to do? Like @Idistic states I must override onPrepareOptionsMenu method, but then what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The onCreateOptionsMenu only gets called once.  There may be a hack that lets you remove an options menu, but the standard way to modify it after that call is as follows from the android docs, note that it says "must"

Changing menu items at runtime

Once the activity is created, the onCreateOptionsMenu() method is called only once, as described above. The system keeps and re-uses the Menu you define in this method until your activity is destroyed. If you want to change the Options Menu any time after it's first created, **you must override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method.**

Documentation is at [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Now having said that you can do this, just not sure if it's supported. This is just my own test code where I swap the menus each time, you will need to add your own logic

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    menu.clear();

    if (OPTIONS_TYPE == 0) {
        OPTIONS_TYPE = 1; 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondmenu, menu);

    }
    else { // Photo + delete option {
        OPTIONS_TYPE = 0;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.firstmenu, menu);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: yeah i've read this.. but what do I do in the onPrepareOptionsMenu?

Comment: I mean I cant use invalidateOptionsMenu() as this is only for android 3.0 and higher ;(

Comment: This problem is solved.. I solved it by overriding the onPrepareOptionsMenu(), calling menu.clear() and then pasting the code in my onCreateOptionsMenu :)

Comment: Yeah I added the second part, you beat me to it though :-)

Comment: Inorder to modify the content of menu at runtime for android version less than  honeycomb,call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() from sherlockActivity.